# Command substitution in Linux - set variables (username and password) in bashrc

Tags: linux, bash, heroku, sendgrid

I am very new to linux. I want to do command substitution. I'd like to define a variable in bashrc and set it equal the return value of a linux command. What's the syntax for it?

Here is exactly what I want to do. I have a Rails 4 app deployed on heroku and I'm using Sendgrid on Heroku to send emails. Now when I type `heroku config:get SENDGRID_USERNAME` (or `heroku config:get SENDGRID_PASSWORD`) in console (in the local folder my_app_folder), it returns my Sendgrid username (or password). I'd like to define a variable, `SENDGRID_USERNAME` in baschrc and set it equal to the return value of `heroku config:get SENDGRID_USERNAME` (instead of copy pasting the actual value). How can I do it? Something like the following:

```
export SENDGRID_USERNAME=my_app_folder/heroku config:get SENDGRID_USERNAME
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you are looking for?

```
SENDGRID_USERNAME=$( path/to/heroku config:get SENDGRID_USERNAME )
#                 ^^                                             ^
```

At execution, the `$( ... )` is replaced by the *output* of the command enclosed in parenthesis. To quote [`man bash`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> ```
> Command Substitution
>
>    Command substitution allows the output of a command to replace the com‐
>    mand name.  There are two forms:
>
>           $(command)
>    or
>           `command`
>
>    Bash performs the expansion by executing command and replacing the com‐
>    mand  substitution  with  the  standard output of the command, with any
>    trailing newlines deleted.
> ```